# How to fill color in particular area?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a castle but I don't know how I fill inside that area(castle) by a particular color. I tried fillstyle but it didn't work maybe I'm not doing right or maybe it needs other thing that I'm not using.
If you need something else, please don't hesitate in ask. I put the snippet to help you guys understand the problem.

```js
function main() {
  var c2d = document.getElementById("acanvas").getContext("2d");
  c2d.fillStyle = "blue";
  castelo(c2d);
}

function castelo(c2d) { //30 para o lado de baixo
  //40 para o lado de cima
  //20 para baixo
  c2d.fillStyle = "red";
  c2d.beginPath();
  c2d.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  c2d.moveTo(20, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(50, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(50, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(50, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(50, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(80, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(80, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(80, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(80, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(120, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(120, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(120, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(120, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(150, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(150, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(150, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(150, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(190, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(190, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(190, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(190, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(220, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(220, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(220, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(220, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(260, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(260, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(260, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(260, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(290, 40);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(290, 40);
  c2d.lineTo(290, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(290, 20);
  c2d.lineTo(320, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(320, 20); //final do castelo em cima
  c2d.lineTo(320, 500);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(320, 500);
  c2d.lineTo(170, 300);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(170, 300);
  c2d.lineTo(20, 500);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.moveTo(20, 500);
  c2d.lineTo(20, 20);
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.closePath();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="capadolivro.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="main();">
  <canvas id="acanvas" width="1366" height="768" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want. There were a few things I modified to make your code work.

- I changed the size of your canvas so it fits more easily in the window for me (you probably have reasons for it being this large on your site)
- I removed the argument from your castelo() function when called, because it isn't needed
- you don't need to do a new moveTo after each line segment, canvas remembers where it last was so you can just lineTo the next spot, this change makes your code about 33% smaller

```js
var c2d = document.getElementById("acanvas").getContext("2d");
if (c2d) {
  castelo()
}

function castelo() { //30 para o lado de baixo
//40 para o lado de cima
//20 para baixo
    c2d.fillStyle= "red";  
    c2d.strokeStyle = "blue";
  c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.moveTo(20,20);
    c2d.lineTo(50,20);
    c2d.lineTo(50,40);
    c2d.lineTo(80,40);
    c2d.lineTo(80,20);
    c2d.lineTo(120,20);
    c2d.lineTo(120,40);
    c2d.lineTo(150,40);
    c2d.lineTo(150,20);
    c2d.lineTo(190,20);
    c2d.lineTo(190,40);
    c2d.lineTo(220,40);
    c2d.lineTo(220,20);
    c2d.lineTo(260,20);
    c2d.lineTo(260,40);
    c2d.lineTo(290,40);
    c2d.lineTo(290,20);
    c2d.lineTo(320,20);  //final do castelo em cima
  c2d.lineTo(320,500);
  c2d.lineTo(170,300);
  c2d.lineTo(20,500);
    c2d.closePath();
  c2d.stroke();
  c2d.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="acanvas" width="600" height="600" />
```

Comment: It is true that you don't need the closePath() at the end for this to work, but I think for someone at ToshiYuki's level, it should be left in so she/he understands how the canvas element works. But again, closePath() is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to `moveTo` every time. Just like this:

```js
function main() {
    var c2d = document.getElementById("acanvas").getContext("2d");

    castelo(c2d);
}

function castelo(c2d) { 
   c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.moveTo(20, 20);
    c2d.lineTo(50,20);
    c2d.lineTo(50,40);
    c2d.lineTo(80,40);
    c2d.lineTo(80,20);
    c2d.lineTo(120,20);
    c2d.lineTo(120,40);
    c2d.lineTo(150,40);
    c2d.lineTo(150,20);
    c2d.lineTo(190,20);
    c2d.lineTo(190,40);   
    c2d.lineTo(220,40);
    c2d.lineTo(220,20);
    c2d.lineTo(260,20);
    c2d.lineTo(260,40);
    c2d.lineTo(290,40);
    c2d.lineTo(290,20);
    c2d.lineTo(320,20);
    c2d.lineTo(320,500);
    c2d.lineTo(170,300);
    c2d.lineTo(20,500);
    c2d.lineTo(20,20);
    c2d.stroke();
    c2d.fillStyle = "red";
    // do not forget about fill(). It also does closePath() for you.
    c2d.fill();  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="capadolivro.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="main();">
        <canvas id="acanvas" width="1366" height="768" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `c2d.fill()` -- setting the fill style isn't enough. But more than that, you have to do `fill()` after the complete outline of your castle has been established as the current path.

You won't be able to just stick `c2d.fill()` at the end of your current code because that would probably fill in all over those lines you've previously stroked.

What you need to do is rearrange your drawing code to do the outline of the castle, both fill then stroke that, then create and stroke any interior detail lines that you want to add.

Comment: and you'll have to set the c2d.fillStyle = "red" or whatever color you want.